# decision trees using R, rpart, fragile families

Tags: rpart

So, I am utilizing the fragile families challenge for my dataset to see which individual and family level predictors predict adolescent academic performance (measured by GPA). Information about my dataset:

FFCWS is a longitudinal panel study in which baseline interviews were conducted in 1998-
2000 with both the mothers and the fathers. Follow-up interviews were conducted when children were aged 1, 3, 5, 9, and 15. Interviews with the parent, primary caregiver(s),
teachers, and children were conducted either in-home or via telephone (FFCWS, 2021). In the
15th year, children/adolescents are asked to report their grades in four subjects- history,
mathematics, English, and science. These grades are averaged for each student to measure their individual academic performance at age 15. A series of individual-level and family-level
predictors that are known to impact the academic performance as mentioned earlier, are also captured at different time points in the life of the child.

I am very new to machine learning and need some guidance. In order to do this, I first create a dataset that contains all the theoretically relevant variables. It is 4,898x15. My final datasets look like this (all are continuous except:

`final <- ffc %>% select(Gender, PPVT, WJ10, Grit, Self-control, Attention, Externalization, Anxiety, Depression, PCG_Income, PCG_Education, Teen_Mom, PCG_Exp, School_connectedness, GPA)`

Then, I split into test and train as follows:
`final_split <- initial_split(final, prop = .7) final_train <- training(final_split) final_test  <- testing(final_split)`

Next, I run the models:
`train <- rpart(GPA ~.,method = "anova", data = final_train, control=rpart.control(cp = 0.2, minsplit = 5, minbucket = 5, maxdepth = 10))  test <-  rpart(GPA ~.,method = "anova", data = final_test, control=rpart.control(cp = 0.2, minsplit = 5, minbucket = 5, maxdepth = 10))`

Next, I visualize cross validation results:
`rpart.plot(train, type = 3, digits = 3, fallen.leaves = TRUE)  rpart.plot(test, type = 3, digits = 3, fallen.leaves = TRUE)`

Next, I run predictions:
`pred_train <- predict(train, ffc.final1_train) pred_test <- predict(test, ffc.final1_test)`

Next, I calculate accuracy:
`MAE <- function(actual, predicted) {mean(abs(actual - predicted)) } MAE(train$GPA, pred_train) MAE(test$GPA, pred_test)`

Following are my questions:

1. Now, I am not sure if I should use rpart or random forest or XG Boost so my first question is that how do I decide which algorithm to use. I decided upon rpart but I want to have a sound reasoning for the same.
2. Are these steps in the right order? What is the point of splitting my dataset into training and testing? I ultimately get two trees (one for train and the other for test). Which ones should I be using? What do I make out of these? A step-by-step procedure after understanding my dataset would be quite helpful. Thanks!